# Getting 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: ' on setSupportActionBar() for Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

After getting past the earlier problem ([Getting 'The method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar) in the type AppCompatActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Toolbar)' in my AppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633867/getting-the-method-setsupportactionbartoolbar-in-the-type-appcompatactivity-i/32633938#32633938)), now setSupportActrionBar() is crashing. Again, here is the relevant code:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class FivetoGo extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                .
                .
                .
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff6d7fe2"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
                        .
                        .
                        .
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and please indicate what line(s) in that stack trace correspond to lines from your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all I needed was to change the parent theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.